# Identifying root parents and all their children in trees

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as such:

```
parent   child   parent_level   child_level
A        B       0              1
B        C       1              2
B        D       1              2
X        Y       0              2
X        D       0              2 
Y        Z       2              3
```

This represents a tree that looks like this

```
       A  X
      /  / \
     B  /   \
    /\ /     \
   C  D       Y
              |
              Z
```

I want to produce something that looks like this:

```
root    children
A       [B,C,D]
X       [D,Y,Z]
```

or

```
root   child
A      B
A      C
A      D
X      D
X      Y
X      Z
```

What is the fastest way to do so without looping. I have a really large dataframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), as this is a graph problem. In particular the [descendants](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html) function:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', 'B', 0, 1],
        ['B', 'C', 1, 2],
        ['B', 'D', 1, 2],
        ['X', 'Y', 0, 2],
        ['X', 'D', 0, 2],
        ['Y', 'Z', 2, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['parent', 'child', 'parent_level', 'child_level'])

roots = df.parent[df.parent_level.eq(0)].unique()
dg = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

result = pd.DataFrame(data=[[root, nx.descendants(dg, root)] for root in roots], columns=['root', 'children'])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  root   children
0    A  {D, B, C}
1    X  {Z, Y, D}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### With Recursion

```
def find_root(tree, child):
    if child in tree:
        return {p for x in tree[child] for p in find_root(tree, x)}
    else:
        return {child}

tree = {}
for parent, child in zip(df.parent, df.child):
    tree.setdefault(child, set()).add(parent)

descendents = {}
for child in tree:
    for parent in find_root(tree, child):
        descendents.setdefault(parent, set()).add(child)

pd.DataFrame(descendents.items(), columns=['root', 'children'])

  root   children
0    A  {B, D, C}
1    X  {Z, D, Y}
```

---

You could alternatively set up `find_root` as a generator

```
def find_root(tree, child):
    if child in tree:
        for x in tree[child]:
            yield from find_root(tree, x)
    else:
        yield child
```

Further, if you want to avoid recursion depth issues, you can use the ["stack of iterators" pattern](http://garethrees.org/2016/09/28/pattern/) to define `find_root`

```
def find_root(tree, child):
    stack = [iter([child])]
    while stack:
        for node in stack[-1]:
            if node in tree:
                stack.append(iter(tree[node]))
            else:
                yield node
            break
        else:  # yes!  that is an `else` clause on a for loop
            stack.pop()
```